# Multiple lists of indices for one array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

In normal situations a list with integers can be used as indices for an array. Let's say

```
arr = np.arange(10)*2
l = [1,2,5]
arr[l] # this gives np.array([2,4,10])
```

Instead of one list of indices, I have several, with different lenghts, an I want to get `arr[l]` for each sublist in my list of indices. How can I achieve this without an sequential approach (using a for), or better, using less time than using a for using numpy?

For example:

```
lists = [[1,2,5], [5,6], [2,8,4]]
arr = np.arange(10)*2
result = np.array([[2,4,10], [10, 12], [4,16,8]]) #this is after the procedure I want to get
```

Comment: I don't think you can avoid using an iterative approach, since your result is a list, not a Numpy type (and you can't make it be a numpy type since the sublist lengths aren't equal).

Comment: the result can be a numpy array, I'm going to edit to show this

Comment: Although `result` is a NumPy array, it has dtype `object`, which is the worst possible type of NumPy array. It is an array of pointers to Python objects. Using such an array is typically slower than using a Python list.

Comment: @AlejandroSazo what about something like this: `[arr[lists[k]] for k in range(len(lists))]`

Comment: @Dalek, That is what I am currently using, I wanted something like vectorized, or faster

Comment: @Dalek that is similar to a for loop and for large slices probably the best option. If there are many tiny slices then you may want to concatenate them.

Comment: @eickenberg but I am getting the same results with your approach.

Comment: I concur with @unutbu that it is useless to make a numpy array out of your result if you expect the result to consist of arrays of different lengths. What you can do is make one big array and store the break points, similarly to how sparse matrices are stored.

Comment: @Dalek hopefully, yes -- the idea behind my answer is for the case where there are a large number of very small array extractions. In that case looping is awful (and obviously the loop I do at the end is not a very good idea: I would store everything differently in that case). If you have few, larger extractions to do, then your approach is probably unbeatable.

Comment: As unutbu says, your edited version is simply a one-dimensional numpy array with three elements whose values are ordinary lists.  This doesn't really gain you anything over using a list of lists.  You're not going to be able to vectorize an operation that doesn't produce some kind of rectangular slice as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the size of your lists whether this makes sense. One option is to concatenate them all, do the slicing and then redistribute into lists.

```
lists = [[1,2,5], [5,6], [2,8,4]]
arr = np.arange(10)*2

extracted = arr[np.concatenate(lists)]

indices = [0] + list(np.cumsum(map(len, lists)))
result = [extracted[indices[i]:indices[i + 1]] for i in range(len(lists))]
```

Or, taking into account @unutbu's comment:

```
result = np.split(extracted, indices[1:-1])
```

Comment: Also possible is: `indices = np.cumsum(map(len, lists))`, `np.split(extracted, indices[:-1])`.

Comment: That is amazingly concise - I didn't know `np.split`.

Comment: I am trying to test the answer but I didn't know I have some empty lists, so the concatenation is made of floats instead of the desired ints:(

Comment: I tried adding an empty list to `lists` and for me the code runs through and returns an empty array at that point, so it works at least on my config. Where do the floats come from? I don't see how they could be introduced.

Comment: with the same example lists and adding an empty list, the concatenation throws an error:

`>>> lists = [[], [1,2,5], [5,6], [2,8,4]]
>>> arr[np.concatenate(lists)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type`

Comment: Very interesting. I get the same, but *only* if the *first* element of `lists` is empty: If you put an empty list anywhere in the middle, it's fine. That means you can just cut off the all the empty lists from the beginning of `lists`, use the code of the answer, and then add the empty lists back to the front of the output.

Comment: Yes! I'm getting time profiles for old code and your answer.

Comment: As I said, it totally depends on how many lists you have and how small they are for this approach to be beneficial.